# Count consecutive NULL values for given ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to create a query that contains a running count of ISO weeks when the account has no entry in a [Volume] table.  The query is to return only a sample of the accounts, so I've created a couple of CTEs to limit the number of records and join the volume table so that weeks with no volume show up in the results.

To illustrate the result I'm looking for:

```
ISOWk | SurrID | Weekly Volume | No vol Count

201601 |    001 |      0 |       1
201601 |    002 |      5 |       0
201602 |    001 |      0 |       2
201602 |    002 |      0 |       1
201603 |    001 |     125|       0
201603 |    002 |     75 |       0
201604 |    001 |      0 |       1
201604 |    002 |     75 |       0
```

As you can see, account with SurrID 001 has no volume for weeks 201601 and 201602 so has [No vol Count] of 2 in week 201602.  In week 201603, there is volume so the counter resets to 0 and increases to 1 week 201604.

From the research I've done I've managed to get a consecutive count running using ROW_NUMBER with a window function, but it doesn't reset if there is volume (as in week 201603 in my example).  What I can't figure out is how to count consecutive zero values and reset when needed.

I've included my full query below so that you get the full picture (please point out any particularly bad practices here - I'm still finding my way!).  It all works as intended until I include the third CTE "NDs".  It then takes 45 mins to return just over 2000 rows and returns an non-resetting count for rows showing no weekly volume.

```
WITH Surrs AS
    (
        SELECT SurrID, OracleStartDate AS OSD
        FROM (
                SELECT ca.SurrID, OracleStartDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OracleStartDate) as rn
                FROM tblCustomerAccounts ca
                JOIN tblAccountUpdates au
                    ON ca.SurrID = au.SurrID
                WHERE CustomerType_ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,12)
                    AND au.ISOWk = 201641
            ) a
        WHERE rn % 1000 = 0
    ),
    Updates AS
    (
        SELECT au.ISOWk, s.SurrID, (CASE WHEN AccStatus_ID = 1 THEN 'A' ELSE 'I' END) AS AccStatus, (CASE WHEN dbo.udf_ConvertDateToISOWeek(OSD) <= BBC THEN 'B' ELSE 'F' END) AS Book
        FROM Surrs s            
        JOIN (
                SELECT  ISOWk,
                        (SELECT BBCutOff FROM dbo.udf_CutOffWeeks(ISOWk)) AS BBC,
                        (SELECT FYStart FROM dbo.udf_CutOffWeeks(ISOWk)) AS FYS,
                        (SELECT FYEnd FROM dbo.udf_CutOffWeeks(ISOWk)) AS FYE,
                        (SELECT BYStart FROM dbo.udf_CutOffWeeks(ISOWk)) AS BYS,
                        (SELECT BYEnd FROM dbo.udf_CutOffWeeks(ISOWk)) AS BYE,
                        SurrID,
                        AccStatus_ID
                FROM tblAccountUpdates
            ) au
            ON au.SurrID = s.SurrID
    ), 
    NDs AS 
    (
        SELECT u.ISOWk, u.SurrID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.SurrID ORDER BY u.ISOWk) AS NDCount
        FROM Updates u
        LEFT JOIN tblTotalVolumes tv
            ON u.SurrID = tv.SurrID
            AND u.ISOWk = tv.ISOWk
        WHERE tv.Volume IS NULL
            AND u.ISOWk >= 201601

    )
SELECT  tw.ISOWk, 
        tw.SurrID, 
        (CASE WHEN Volume IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Volume END) AS [Weekly Volume], 
        tw.Book, 
        tw.AccStatus,
        (CASE WHEN tw.AccStatus = 'I' AND lw.AccStatus = 'A' THEN 'Y' ELSE '' END) AS [Stopped this week],
        (CASE WHEN tw.AccStatus = 'A' AND lw.AccStatus = 'I' THEN 'Y' ELSE '' END) AS [Restarted this week],
        (CASE WHEN NDCount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE NDCount END) AS [Consecutive ND Weeks]

FROM Updates tw
JOIN Updates lw
    ON lw.ISOWk = dbo.udf_ConvertDateToISOWeek(DATEADD("ww",-1,dbo.udf_ConvertISOWkToDate(tw.ISOWk)))
    AND tw.SurrID = lw.SurrID
LEFT JOIN tblTotalVolumes tv
    ON tw.SurrID = tv.SurrID
    AND tw.ISOWk = tv.ISOWk
LEFT JOIN NDs
    ON tw.SurrID = nds.SurrID
    AND tw.ISOWk = nds.ISOWk

ORDER BY tw.ISOWk
```

To reiterate what I need: the column [Consecutive ND Weeks] should count consecutive weeks where [Weekly Volume] is 0.  Help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE:

I've tried to implement @Gordon Linoff's post but my counter does not reset to 0 when there is a value for [Weekly Volume].  Here's my amended query:

```
SELECT t.*, (CASE WHEN [Weekly Volume] = 0 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.SurrID, grp ORDER BY ISOWk) ELSE 0 END) AS [ND Count]

FROM (
        SELECT  tw.ISOWk, 
                s.SurrID, 
                tw.AccStatus,
                (CASE WHEN tv.Volume IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE tv.Volume END) AS [Weekly Volume],
                (CASE WHEN dbo.udf_ConvertDateToISOWeek(OSD) <= BBC THEN 'B' ELSE 'F' END) AS Book,
                (CASE WHEN tw.AccStatus = 'I' AND lw.AccStatus = 'A' THEN 'Y' ELSE '' END) AS [Stopped this week],
                (CASE WHEN tw.AccStatus = 'A' AND lw.AccStatus = 'I' THEN 'Y' ELSE '' END) AS [Restarted this week],
                SUM(CASE WHEN tv.volume > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY tv.SurrID ORDER BY tv.ISOWk) AS grp

        FROM (
                SELECT SurrID, OracleStartDate AS OSD
                FROM (
                        SELECT ca.SurrID, OracleStartDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OracleStartDate) as rn
                        FROM tblCustomerAccounts ca
                        JOIN tblAccountUpdates au
                            ON ca.SurrID = au.SurrID
                        WHERE CustomerType_ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,12)
                            AND au.ISOWk = 201641
                    ) a
                WHERE rn % 1000 = 0
            ) s         
        JOIN (
                SELECT  ISOWk,
                        (SELECT BBCutOff FROM dbo.udf_CutOffWeeks(ISOWk)) AS BBC,
                        (SELECT FYStart FROM dbo.udf_CutOffWeeks(ISOWk)) AS FYS,
                        (SELECT FYEnd FROM dbo.udf_CutOffWeeks(ISOWk)) AS FYE,
                        (SELECT BYStart FROM dbo.udf_CutOffWeeks(ISOWk)) AS BYS,
                        (SELECT BYEnd FROM dbo.udf_CutOffWeeks(ISOWk)) AS BYE,
                        SurrID,
                        (CASE WHEN AccStatus_ID = 1 THEN 'A' ELSE 'I' END) AS AccStatus
                FROM tblAccountUpdates
            ) tw
            ON tw.SurrID = s.SurrID
        JOIN (
                SELECT  ISOWk,
                        SurrID,
                        (CASE WHEN AccStatus_ID = 1 THEN 'A' ELSE 'I' END) AS AccStatus
                FROM tblAccountUpdates
            ) lw
            ON tw.SurrID = lw.SurrID
            AND dbo.udf_ConvertDateToISOWeek(DATEADD("ww",-1,dbo.udf_ConvertISOWkToDate(tw.ISOWk))) = lw.ISOWk
        LEFT JOIN tblTotalVolumes tv
            ON tw.ISOWk = tv.ISOWk
            AND tw.SurrID = tv.SurrID
    ) t

ORDER BY ISOWk
```

UPDATE:

I've now modified my query to reflect Vladimir's solution (once again, this is the full query):

```
SELECT  ISOWk, 
        SurrID, 
        AccStatus, 
        [Weekly Volume], 
        Book, 
        [Stopped this week], 
        [Restarted this week],
        RN1,
        RN2,
        grp,
        rn3,
        (CASE WHEN [Weekly Volume] = 0 THEN rn3 ELSE 0 END) AS [ND Count]
FROM (
        SELECT  t.ISOWk,
                t.SurrID,
                t.AccStatus,
                t.[Weekly Volume],
                t.Book,
                t.[Stopped this week],
                t.[Restarted this week],
                rn1,
                rn2,
                rn1 - rn2 AS grp,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.SurrID, rn1-rn2 ORDER BY ISOWk) AS rn3

        FROM (
                SELECT  tw.ISOWk, 
                        s.SurrID, 
                        tw.AccStatus,
                        (CASE WHEN tv.Volume IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE tv.Volume END) AS [Weekly Volume],
                        (CASE WHEN dbo.udf_ConvertDateToISOWeek(OSD) <= BBC THEN 'B' ELSE 'F' END) AS Book,
                        (CASE WHEN tw.AccStatus = 'I' AND lw.AccStatus = 'A' THEN 'Y' ELSE '' END) AS [Stopped this week],
                        (CASE WHEN tw.AccStatus = 'A' AND lw.AccStatus = 'I' THEN 'Y' ELSE '' END) AS [Restarted this week],
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tw.SurrID ORDER BY tw.ISOWk) AS rn1,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tw.SurrID, tv.Volume ORDER BY tw.ISOWk) AS rn2

                FROM (
                        SELECT SurrID, OracleStartDate AS OSD
                        FROM (
                                SELECT ca.SurrID, OracleStartDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OracleStartDate) as rn
                                FROM tblCustomerAccounts ca
                                JOIN tblAccountUpdates au
                                    ON ca.SurrID = au.SurrID
                                WHERE CustomerType_ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,12)
                                    AND au.ISOWk = 201641
                            ) a
                        WHERE rn % 2000 = 0
                    ) s         
                JOIN (
                        SELECT  ISOWk,
                                (SELECT BBCutOff FROM dbo.udf_CutOffWeeks(ISOWk)) AS BBC,
                                (SELECT FYStart FROM dbo.udf_CutOffWeeks(ISOWk)) AS FYS,
                                (SELECT FYEnd FROM dbo.udf_CutOffWeeks(ISOWk)) AS FYE,
                                (SELECT BYStart FROM dbo.udf_CutOffWeeks(ISOWk)) AS BYS,
                                (SELECT BYEnd FROM dbo.udf_CutOffWeeks(ISOWk)) AS BYE,
                                SurrID,
                                (CASE WHEN AccStatus_ID = 1 THEN 'A' ELSE 'I' END) AS AccStatus
                        FROM tblAccountUpdates
                    ) tw
                    ON tw.SurrID = s.SurrID
                JOIN (
                        SELECT  ISOWk,
                                SurrID,
                                (CASE WHEN AccStatus_ID = 1 THEN 'A' ELSE 'I' END) AS AccStatus
                        FROM tblAccountUpdates
                    ) lw
                    ON tw.SurrID = lw.SurrID
                    AND dbo.udf_ConvertDateToISOWeek(DATEADD("ww",-1,dbo.udf_ConvertISOWkToDate(tw.ISOWk))) = lw.ISOWk
                LEFT JOIN tblTotalVolumes tv
                    ON tw.ISOWk = tv.ISOWk
                    AND tw.SurrID = tv.SurrID

            ) t
    ) x

ORDER BY ISOWk
```

Here's a sample of the unexpected (in that the counter doesn't reset to 0 when [Weekly Volume] has a value greater than 0, identified with the asterisks) results.  The following all have the same ID, so I've removed the ID column.

```
ISOWk  | Weekly Volume | rn1 | rn2 | grp | rn3 | ND Count |
201620 |            0  |  1  |  1  |  0  |  1  |    1     |
201621 |            0  |  2  |  2  |  0  |  2  |    2     |
201622 |            0  |  3  |  3  |  0  |  3  |    3     |
201623 |            0  |  4  |  4  |  0  |  4  |    4     |
201624 |            0  |  5  |  5  |  0  |  5  |    5     |
201625 |           53  |  6  |  1  |  5  |  1  |    0     |
201626 |           49  |  7  |  1  |  6  |  1  |    0     |
201627 |           98  |  8  |  1  |  7  |  1  |    0     |
201628 |           54  |  9  |  1  |  8  |  1  |    0     |
201629 |           53  | 10  |  2  |  8  |  2  |    0     |
201630 |          103  | 11  |  1  | 10  |  1  |    0     |
201631 |           59  | 12  |  1  | 11  |  1  |    0     |
201632 |           35  | 13  |  1  | 12  |  1  |    0     |
201633 |            0  | 14  |  6  |  8  |  3  |    3     |**
201634 |            0  | 15  |  7  |  8  |  4  |    4     |**
201635 |            0  | 16  |  8  |  8  |  5  |    5     |**
201636 |            0  | 17  |  9  |  8  |  6  |    6     |**
201637 |           87  | 18  |  1  | 17  |  1  |    0     |
201638 |          136  | 19  |  1  | 18  |  1  |    0     |
201639 |           56  | 20  |  1  | 19  |  1  |    0     |
201640 |           70  | 21  |  1  | 20  |  0  |    0     |
201641 |           77  | 22  |  1  | 21  |  1  |    0     |
```

There are other instances of this issue in my dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a `gaps-and-islands` problem.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(ISOWk int, SurrID char(3), WeeklyVolume int);
INSERT INTO @T(ISOWk, SurrID, WeeklyVolume) VALUES
(201601, '001',  0),
(201601, '002',  5),
(201602, '001',  0),
(201602, '002',  0),
(201603, '001',125),
(201603, '002', 75),
(201604, '001',  0),
(201604, '002', 75),
(201620, '003',  0),
(201621, '003',  0),
(201622, '003',  0),
(201623, '003',  0),
(201624, '003',  0),
(201625, '003', 53),
(201626, '003', 49),
(201627, '003', 98),
(201628, '003', 54),
(201629, '003', 53),
(201630, '003',103),
(201631, '003', 59),
(201632, '003', 35),
(201633, '003',  0),
(201634, '003',  0),
(201635, '003',  0),
(201636, '003',  0),
(201637, '003', 87),
(201638, '003',136),
(201639, '003', 56),
(201640, '003', 70),
(201641, '003', 77),
(201601, '004',  0),
(201602, '004',  6),
(201603, '004',  0),
(201604, '004',  0);
```

I added your extended sample with `SurrID=003` and added mine sample with `SurrID=004`.

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ISOWk
        ,SurrID
        ,WeeklyVolume
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SurrID ORDER BY ISOWk) AS rn1
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SurrID,WeeklyVolume ORDER BY ISOWk) AS rn2
    FROM @T
)
,CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT
        ISOWk
        ,SurrID
        ,WeeklyVolume
        ,rn1
        ,rn2
        ,rn1-rn2 AS grp
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SurrID,WeeklyVolume,rn1-rn2 ORDER BY ISOWk) AS rn3
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT
    ISOWk
    ,SurrID
    ,WeeklyVolume
    ,rn1
    ,rn2
    ,grp
    ,rn3
    ,CASE WHEN WeeklyVolume = 0 THEN rn3 ELSE 0 END AS NoVolumeCount
FROM CTE2
ORDER BY SurrID, ISOWk;
```

**Result**

```
+--------+--------+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------+
| ISOWk  | SurrID | WeeklyVolume | rn1 | rn2 | grp | rn3 | NoVolumeCount |
+--------+--------+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------+
| 201601 |    001 |            0 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   1 |             1 |
| 201602 |    001 |            0 |   2 |   2 |   0 |   2 |             2 |
| 201603 |    001 |          125 |   3 |   1 |   2 |   1 |             0 |
| 201604 |    001 |            0 |   4 |   3 |   1 |   1 |             1 |
| 201601 |    002 |            5 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   1 |             0 |
| 201602 |    002 |            0 |   2 |   1 |   1 |   1 |             1 |
| 201603 |    002 |           75 |   3 |   1 |   2 |   1 |             0 |
| 201604 |    002 |           75 |   4 |   2 |   2 |   2 |             0 |
| 201620 |    003 |            0 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   1 |             1 |
| 201621 |    003 |            0 |   2 |   2 |   0 |   2 |             2 |
| 201622 |    003 |            0 |   3 |   3 |   0 |   3 |             3 |
| 201623 |    003 |            0 |   4 |   4 |   0 |   4 |             4 |
| 201624 |    003 |            0 |   5 |   5 |   0 |   5 |             5 |
| 201625 |    003 |           53 |   6 |   1 |   5 |   1 |             0 |
| 201626 |    003 |           49 |   7 |   1 |   6 |   1 |             0 |
| 201627 |    003 |           98 |   8 |   1 |   7 |   1 |             0 |
| 201628 |    003 |           54 |   9 |   1 |   8 |   1 |             0 |
| 201629 |    003 |           53 |  10 |   2 |   8 |   1 |             0 |
| 201630 |    003 |          103 |  11 |   1 |  10 |   1 |             0 |
| 201631 |    003 |           59 |  12 |   1 |  11 |   1 |             0 |
| 201632 |    003 |           35 |  13 |   1 |  12 |   1 |             0 |
| 201633 |    003 |            0 |  14 |   6 |   8 |   1 |             1 |
| 201634 |    003 |            0 |  15 |   7 |   8 |   2 |             2 |
| 201635 |    003 |            0 |  16 |   8 |   8 |   3 |             3 |
| 201636 |    003 |            0 |  17 |   9 |   8 |   4 |             4 |
| 201637 |    003 |           87 |  18 |   1 |  17 |   1 |             0 |
| 201638 |    003 |          136 |  19 |   1 |  18 |   1 |             0 |
| 201639 |    003 |           56 |  20 |   1 |  19 |   1 |             0 |
| 201640 |    003 |           70 |  21 |   1 |  20 |   1 |             0 |
| 201641 |    003 |           77 |  22 |   1 |  21 |   1 |             0 |
| 201601 |    004 |            0 |   1 |   1 |   0 |   1 |             1 |
| 201602 |    004 |            6 |   2 |   1 |   1 |   1 |             0 |
| 201603 |    004 |            0 |   3 |   2 |   1 |   1 |             1 |
| 201604 |    004 |            0 |   4 |   3 |   1 |   2 |             2 |
+--------+--------+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------+
```

I included intermediate columns in the result, so you can understand how it works.

Standard approach for `gaps-and-islands` is two sequences of `ROW_NUMBER` - one is a plain sequence (`rn1`), second is partitioned by `WeeklyVolume` (`rn2`).

The difference between `rn1` and `rn2` gives the ID of the group (island) (`grp`). Calculate another sequence of row numbers partitioned by `WeeklyVolume` and this group (`rn3`) and use it only when `WeeklyVolume` is zero.

Obviously, everything above is partitioned by `SurrID` at first.

In the first variant of the answer I forgot to include `WeeklyVolume` in the last partitioning for `rn3`.

Comment: This works largely as expected.  However, there seems to be some combinations of values that result in the same value for `grp`, despite the `Weekly Volume` values not being the same; thus resulting in erroneous `NoVolCount` value.  Is this possible, or is my implementation wrong (in the context of the question)?

Comment: @AndrewWilliams, please extend the sample data, show us these special combinations and show us what result you expect.

Comment: Perfect.  That gives me the result I'd expect.  Your suggestion was very helpful because of the example data you provided and I can clearly see how this is working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach:

1. Count the number of preceding non-0 values for `SurrId`.  This number identifies groups.
2. Do a `row_number()` within each group.
3. Only consider the `row_number()` when the value is `0`.

This results in:

```
select t.*,
       (case when weeklyvolume = 0
             then row_number() over (partition by SurrId, grp order by ISOwk)
             else 0
        end) as NoVolCount
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when weeklyvolume > 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by SurrId order by ISOwk) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: I've amended my query so that I can use your format but the `[NoVolCount]` doesn't reset when a row has Weekly Volume, unless, that is, I've implemented your solution incorrectly.  I've edited my post and would be grateful if you'd have a look.